# Solving Matrix question AX=B to find the possible solutions of B

Tags: matrices

### Question

> Find $b_1$ and $b_2$ so that the equation $Ax = b$ has solutions where
>   $$A = 
> \begin{bmatrix}
> 1 & 2 \\
> 0 & 1\\
> -1 & 2
> \end{bmatrix};\quad 
> b = 
> \begin{bmatrix}
> b_1 \\
> b_2 \\
> 0
> \end{bmatrix}.$$
>   Can this equation have a unique solution? Why or why not?

### Work

$$\begin{bmatrix}1&2 \\0&1\\-1&2\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}b_1\\b_2\\0\end{bmatrix}$$

$$\begin{bmatrix}
x_1 + 2x_2 \\
x_2 \\
-x_1 + 2x_2
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
b_1 \\
b_2 \\
0 
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$\left.\begin{array}{ll}
x_1 + 2x_2 = b_1 \\
x_2 = b_2 \\
2x_2 = x_1 
\end{array}\right\} \Rightarrow \left.\begin{array}{ll}x_1 = b_1/2 \\
x_2 = b_1/4 \end{array}\right\} \Rightarrow b_1/4 = b_2 \Rightarrow b_1 = 4b_2$$

Comment: This is not a do-my-homework-for-me site.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Comment: To all reviewers: [OP's work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDxkA.jpg) is *hidden* in the comments of the answer.

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會 Thank you for the heads up. I edited the question to reflect their work and the problem statement -- let me know if this is reasonable.

Answer (score -1):

Hint: the equation $Ax=b$ has solutions $ \iff rank(A|b)=rank(A)$.

Comment: This is what I've done so far

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDxkA.jpg.

Could you kindly please look and give a little more detail on it

Comment: @Rad Please post your work *inside* the question body, and *use MathJax* to typeset them.  You may search for "mathjax tutorial" on [meta] for typing math on this site.