# Stuck on a Ax=B matrix question, need confirmation if my work is correct

Tags: matrices

[image: This is the question]

[image: This is my work so far]

So from the matrix question we have, will it be possible to have 2 distinct real roots for $b_1$ and $b_2$? Or am I supposed to leave them as I did (in a relation with each other?)

Also is that what I'm supposed to explain in the second part where they ask about a unique solution?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you created what’s essentially a duplicate of [the previous question you asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2939109/265466) not long before this instead of updating that one with your efforts?

Comment: I couldn't find the option to edit the question as I'm in mobile, so I just this one with my work in it

Answer (score 1):

You found that if $b_1=4b_2$ then there is only one solution which is $x_1=\frac{b_1}{2},x_2=\frac{b_1}{4}$. So you actually showed that if a solution exists it must be unique.

Comment: So is there anything else I might have to add, or is that it?

Comment: Nothing to add, your solution is correct. But please, next time when you ask a question try to post it here instead of giving links. It will be much easier for people to read it then.

Comment: Yeah sure, thanks for letting me know. This is my first time here